# Player keys wont respond when player jumping

Tags: python, pygame

So I been working on the sides of my player and I did it and I am just having this one problem, It is that when my player jump's while trying move, my player wont respond to the key I press. The keys only respond when the player starts falling down.

gyazo.com/17bd10445460cd358c6dba4d99e106a7

It is pretty hard to jump to other platforms while this is happening, It started to happen right after I made my player touch the sides of my platform.

I'm not sure where its happening but this is where I made my player jump

```
        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                py -= playerman.speed
            playerman.fall = 0
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")

# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())

class bullet(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 10
        self.color = color
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = round(self.x), round(self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Colors for hitbox
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(255,255,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(0,0,40,500,green)
platform2 = Platform(40,460,700,40,green)

# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2]

# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    # Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()

x = 10
y = 10
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            x_change = -7
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 7

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x
           
    # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
        px -= playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_d] and px < 700 - playerman.height - playerman.speed:
        px += playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and py > playerman.speed:
        py -= playerman.speed
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and py <500 - playerman.width - playerman.speed:
        py += playerman.speed

    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    if not playerman.isJump and player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px
  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
                       
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                py -= playerman.speed
            playerman.fall = 0

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    redrawwindow()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop ignores the X movement when jumping.

Change this:

```
if not playerman.isJump and player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px
```

To This:

```
# if not playerman.isJump and 
if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
    playerman.x = px
```